# Why can I modify a string literal with CLion?

Tags: c, string, pointers, char, string-literals

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char *name = "Thank you";
    name[0] = 'a';
    printf("%s", name);
}
```

and it works fine:

[image: it works]

My understanding is that `name[0] = 'a'` should not work.

So why is it working?

Answer (score 2):

C standard imposes no restriction on attempting to modify a string literal. However, if you attempt to modify a string literal, the outcome is [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Quoting `C11`, chapter 6.4.5 (String literals)/P7

> *[...] If the program attempts to modify such an array, the behavior is undefined.*

The fact that you think the program is allowing you to modify the content of the string literal is one of the many outcome of the UB.

Comment: Your first two sentences seem to say the exact opposite of each other.

Comment: @interjay I don't think so. It says, there's nothing in C that should throw an error or stop you from doing (i.e., writing code to perform) that, but if you do, the result is UB.

Comment: That's a rather strange and misleading way to look at things. I'd say that UB is definitely something that should stop you from doing that. It's like saying "There's nothing that prevents you from using an undeclared identifier, but if you do you'll get a compiler error".

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is almost correct, the program is indeed ill-formed, but that doesn't mean that it should malfunction or othewise fail, it invokes undefined behavior.

Unfortunately, one of the possible symptoms of undefined behavior is the appearence that the program is behaving as it should.

Undefined behavior as described in [N1570 ISO/IEC 9899:201x §3.4.3](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#3.4.3)

> 1 **undefined behavior**
>
> Behavior, upon use of a nonportable or erroneous program construct or of erroneous data, for which this International Standard imposes no requirements.
>
> 2 **NOTE**
>
> Possible undefined behavior ranges from ignoring the situation completely with unpredictable results, to behaving during translation or program execution in a documented manner characteristic of the environment (with or without the issuance of a diagnostic message), to terminating a translation or execution (with the issuance of a diagnostic message).